# RecyclerView does not scroll on landscape mode. It works after rotation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/actions_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:elevation="@dimen/padding_default" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/actions_recycler_view"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <include layout="@layout/horizontal_line" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I set LinearlayoutManager as follows:

```
RecyclerView actionsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.actions_recycler_view);
actionsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
    new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
actionsRecyclerView.setAdapter(actionsAdapter);
```

It works perfect on many devices but on Samsung SM-T258 (android 5.1.1) id does not work at landscape mode. It doesn't work, I mean it does not scroll by swiping to left and right. I have to rotate tablet and rotate again so `RecyclerView` starts working!
Could anybody help me in this regard?

Comment: facing the same thing, don't have any work around yet.